# How to make Eclipse show packages?

Tags: eclipse, package, upgrade

I recently upgraded my Eclipse and the workspace stopped working.

So I made a new one, copied all my projects over to it, then imported them.

However, now it shows them as folders instead of the actual packages like it used to:

[image: Here is a picture of the folders.]

How can I get the packages back?

Comment: The screenshot shows the _Package Explorer_ or the _Project Explorer_ view, not the _Navigator_ view, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you are using the Eclipse perspective *Java* or *Java EE* and within one of those perspectives, are using the view *Package Explorer* ?

[image: Eclipse - Package Explorer view]

Most of the times this happening because the Eclipse view *Navigator* is used, as show here.

[image: Eclipse - Navigator view]